# Why is this function not returning the list of values?

Tags: python, linked-list

By printing the array "total", I can see that the values are appending correctly. And yet when I print(linked_list_values(a)), it returns None.

```
a = Node(5)
b = Node(3)
c = Node(9)
total = []
def linked_list_values(head):
  print(total)
  if head == None:
     return None
  total.append(head.num)
  linked_list_values(head.next)
print(linked_list_values(a))
```

Answer (score 2):

The function returns `None` because you never have a `return` statement in it. It **does** mutate `total`, but it gets mutated in-place.

Try printing the value of `total` after the function runs.

```py
>>> linked_list_values(a)
None
>>> total
[5, 3, 9] # Assuming a.next == b and b.next == c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't returning anything for the statement at the bottom to print meaning Python is gonna read the return value of your function as None. A simple fix would be to add a return statement after the recursive call.

```
a = Node(5)
b = Node(3) 
c = Node(9) 
total = [] 
def linked_list_values(head):  
    if head == None:  
        return None 
    total.append(head.num) 
    linked_list_values(head.next)
    return total 
print(linked_list_values(a))
```